# Update data with existing table in loop

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a loop with a while statement, in the first step I created a table `#dane_wszystko` and then want to overwrite table `#dane_wszystko` with data from `#dane_wszystko` and data from `#dane_dzielone`.

I have tried with many options, but all the time fails.

```
if @i = 1 
begin
    select * into #dane_wszystko from #dane_dzielone
end

if @i > 1
begin
    ;with ctm as (
        select * from #dane_wszystko
        union all
        select * from #dane_dzielone
    )
    update #dane_wszystko
    set partycja = @i
    from ctm
end
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (and your code is invalid standard SQL). Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: *but all the time fails* - that's not a standard SQL Error, add clarity.

Comment: You practically *never* want to use loops with relational databases. Explain what `@i` is and where it comes from, what `partycja`  is, show sample data and show the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a table inside the loop, and you plan to overwrite it, make sure you drop it before.

You can use:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TableName
```